# Showing that the operation on the category of Relations is associative?

Tags: category-theory, predicate-logic

Consider the category of Relations, whose objects are sets and morphisms are relations $R:A \rightarrow B$ if $R\subset A \times B$ is relation. Compostion is defined by $S \circ R:=\{(a,c)| \exists b \in B  \, \text{ with } (a,b)\in R \, \, (b,c)\in S\}$ where $R \subset A \times B$ and $S \subset B\times C$.

I want to show that this is a category.  Clearly the identity morphism is given by relation $1_A=A \times A$. I am trying to show associativity but I'm slightly confused. I can see the argument that you would write down but I am not sure why it is justified.

If we have $T \circ (S \circ R)=\{(a,d)| \exists c \in C  \, \text{ with } (a,c)\in S \circ R \, \, (c,d)\in T\}$, I am confused about how the quantifiers work when we trying to replace $(a,c) \in S\circ R$ with the conditions for being in $S\circ R$.

I don't know how justify going from here to what would be the correct answer $T \circ (S \circ R)=\{(a,d)| \exists c \in C  \, \text{ with } (\exists b \in B  \, \text{ with } (a,b)\in R \, \, (b,c)\in S) \, \, (c,d)\in T\}$.

If I could show that this was the same as $T \circ (S \circ R)=\{(a,d)| \exists c \in C \, \exists b \in B \, \text{with} (a,b)\in R \, (b,c)\in S, (c,d)\in T\}$ then we would be done

Comment: Why do you think those two descriptions of $T \circ (S \circ R)$ are not the same? They are expressing exactly the same, it's just a different wording.

Comment: Can you prove that in either of these, we have $(a,d)$ iff there are $b\in B$ and $c\in C$ with $(a,b)\in R$, $(b,c)\in S$ and $(c,d)\in T$?

Comment: @Rick i thought there might be some kind of dependances with the existence, like how you can't just swap "for all there exists" and "there exists for all"

Comment: @AnginaSeng i think i can show this to be a case but is there a more general reason why the existence of b need not have depend on the existence of c

Comment: @MarkMurray but there is no “for all” in your condition. All you’ve done is delete a parenthesis and a meaningless “with”, so it’s quite unclear what difference you could be worried about. Either condition just means there are $b$ and $c$ with $(a,b),(b,c),(c,d)$ in the desired relations. What else could it mean?

Comment: Also you claim the identity is clearly $A\times A$, which is actually not so clear, because it's not the identity.

Comment: @MarkMurray I think by $1_A = A\times A$ you might have meant $1_A = (1_A', 1_A') $ the unique morphism (a relation) $A\rightarrow A\times A$ which takes $a$ to $(a, a)$. (By $1_A'$, I mean the identity 'function' on set $A$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that $X = Y$ iff $w \, X\, z \;=\; e \, Y \, z$
for any elements $w, z$.

$\def\BEGINstep{ \langle }
\def\ENDstep{ \rangle }
\newcommand{\step}[2][=]{ \\ #1 \;\; & \qquad \color{maroon}{\BEGINstep \text{ #2 } \ENDstep} \\ & }
\newenvironment{calc}{\begin{align*} & }{\end{align*}}$

---

\begin{calc}
   w \,(T ∘ (S ∘ R))\, z
\step{ definition of  composition }
   ∃ x. \quad w \,T\, x \, (S ∘ R) \, z
\step{ definition of composition, and “and” distributes over ∃ }
   ∃ x, y. \quad w \,T\, x \, S\, y \,R \, z
\step{ definition of composition, and “and” distributes over ∃ }
   ∃ y. \quad w \,(T ∘ S)\, y \,R \, z
\step{ definition of composition }
   w \,((T ∘ S) ∘ R)\, z  
\end{calc}

Comment: I think "and" distrubuting of over existence was the thing I was missing, thank you very much